# iText "PDF header signature not found" with Google docs pdf

Tags: pdf, itext, google-docs, drive

We have been using iText for over a year now to generate pdf's of Google Docs (on drive) with custom headers and footers.

To do this we read in the pdf of the google doc as follows:

```
URL url =  DriveController.getUrlFromFile(fileId);
if(url != null) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(url);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    ....

public static URL getUrlFromFile(String fileId) {
    fileId = "1macLOQW0YG9KMq0iTiMkMbs4-be07fNWtWAksVkjVvk";
    Drive service = null;
    try {

        service = DriveDirectoryServiceManager.getDriveService(SERVICE_ACCOUNT);
        File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
        try {
            if (file.getExportLinks() != null) {
                return new URL(file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf"));
                .....
```

Since the 23rd of March iText is throwing "`com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.`" on this line:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(url);
```

No code changes where made and the bizar thing is that the URL to the pdf seems to return a perfectly fine pdf when you browse to it manually in a browser.

When I examine the content inputstream of the content returned by the URL I can see that it starts with "%PDF-1.5" which seems fine and also the headers of the returned URL seem perfectly fine:

```
{
cache-control=[private, max-age=0],
content-type=[application/pdf; charset=utf-8],
date=[Mon, 27 Mar 2017 09:23:24 GMT],
expires=[Mon, 27 Mar 2017 09:23:24 GMT],
x-robots-tag=[noindex, nofollow, nosnippet],
content-disposition=[attachment;filename="BUCK-PP-6L-RO-HNDL-209-211-QDS-GLOB-PMS0001.pdf"],
transfer-encoding=[chunked],
p3p=[CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info.", CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."],
x-content-type-options=[nosniff],
x-frame-options=[SAMEORIGIN],
x-xss-protection=[1; mode=block],
server=[GSE],
set-cookie=[NID=99=m3XiYqz60y3VfDLAXLLcMnakRT7TbAYOqFABcvJIuRM8hs8zo9yfylmcnPY4y0bTv-j2RjVf4QTj7dC7TKTE-Mvg1lZlpGQJl0Q1EmbfjYHZtx8RqYLjtbNMIc18Ac6J;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Tue, 26-Sep-2017 09:23:24 GMT;HttpOnly, NID=99=FO3FQ6tVAsgeq2_GbdJlOSCVegOfqgou2uR_uc_tIkeXhUbXVnrgHrV9SJIz01-IhlE5SmUf5caLYhN1rlnVo0ROcYlzozBwCESPOWOEHnFZhHl3Nv99q7MCiUu-AUro;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Tue, 26-Sep-2017 09:23:24 GMT;HttpOnly],
alt-svc=[quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"]
}
```

Any help is welcome if anyone has any idea as to why iText does not recognize it as a pdf.

[Input stream to string image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3NVM.png)

Kind regards

Comment: Which version of iText do you use? `com.itextpdf.text.*` indicates that it's probably 5.x.x, but which version exactly? You write that no code changes were made. Do you use Maven and which iText version did you put in your POM file?

Comment: We use gradle: The version we use is 5.5.6 (compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6')

Comment: Okay. Could you try with 5.5.11? Although honestly I don't expect a difference. For debugging purposes, could you save the pdf to a file before you process it with iText?

Comment: My next step will be to ask you to share your PDF, but maybe you don't want to put it on the public internet. Could you check if your company has a support contract with iText? Then we can treat that pdf as confidential data and track the issue in our internal support system.

Comment: *I can see that it starts with %PDF-1.5 which seems fine* - Are you sure it really starts with that or might there be some white space characters in front of that?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: Updated to 5.5.11 but as you indicated this does not solve the issue. Saving the pdf as a file is not possible since we are working on app engine (outputstreams are restricted on app engine)
The file I use is this one: I can not share it publically but feel free to request access. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1macLOQW0YG9KMq0iTiMkMbs4-be07fNWtWAksVkjVvk/edit

Comment: @mkl: I'll add a screenshot of the logs I get when we log the inputstream that is in the content of the pdf url to a string with IOUtils StringWriter

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the file separately into a byte array and opening it in a PdfReader generated from that byte array?

Comment: @mkl: retrieving the file to a byte array first did the trick. A big thank you sir!

Comment: Probably there is some redirect now which your Web client follows but itext does not? Well, in my opinion it is better anyways to separate the steps of retrieving the data via the net and processing them, if only for the sake of easier analysis and more concise error messages.